# Can't use value resolved from and returned from promise

Tags: javascript, mysql, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

In the code below, I grab a Table object (from mysql/xdevapi).  The getSchema() and getTable() methods return objects, not promises.  My intent is for this function to return a Table object (fulfilled value) that I can use in other code synchronously.

```
// dbutils.js    
var mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');
var settings = require('./settings');

exports.getTable = (tableName) => {
  return mysqlx.getSession(settings.connectionProperties)
  .then(dbSession => {
    let table = dbSession.getSchema('shizbot').getTable(tableName);
    console.log("dbutils.getTable is returning table: " + table.getName())
    return table;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

When I call the above method from this code, however, I get TypeError trying to execute a method on the returned Table object, and the Table object's value logs as {}.  (Incidentally, I have other code that uses the Table object just fine when it's used inside of the above then() method.)

```
// db_user.js
var dbutils = require('./dbutils');

function getUserTable() {
  let table = dbutils.getTable('user');
  console.log("table: " + JSON.stringify(table));  //  table: {}  ???
  console.log("dbuser.getUserTable is returning table: " + 
  table.getName()) // TypeError: table.getName is not a function
return table;
}
```

Moreover, my logs show an unexpected order of events.  What is going on?   I realize that I can (and probably should) take advantage of the promise and rewrite my code downstream, but why doesn't this code work?  I'm trying to understand better how to mix async and sync code.

Thanks!

```
Console Output:
running /authenticate route.
table: {}
Error while authenticating: TypeError: table.getName is not a function
POST /admin/authenticate 500 24.089 ms - 40
dbutils.getTable is returning table: user
```

Comment: In `getUserTable()`, `table` is a promise, not the value it resolves to.

Comment: Also, you point out that the `getSchema()` and `getTable()` methods return objects, not promises, but you forget that `getSession()` _does_ return a promise, which is why my above statement is true. You can't fulfill a promise synchronously, but you can declare `getUserTable()` as `async` and instead do `let table = await dbutils.getTable('user')`, but then `getUserTable()` would return a promise that resolves to `table`.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts.  Not disputing, just confused.  I get the async/await strategy you're suggesting, but I still don't see how it is that I'm returning a promise.  Doesn't `(dbSession) => { session ...}` resolve that to a session value?  If, per the mysql api, getSchema.getTable returned a promise, then I see your point, but per the docs that's not the case.  [see api](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/Session.html) . I have other code that uses the table object inside of the then method just fine.  It's only when I return that value that I see problems.

Comment: Your link to the API refers to documentation for the `dbSession` object, but [`mysqlx.getSession()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-nodejs/8.0/module-mysqlx.html) returns a promise as I said.

Comment: After some thought I realized my blind spot on this, and I'm accepting @PatrickRoberts answer on this.  I see now that I was incorrectly assuming that if a promise.then resolves to a value object then I could expect at that point to work with that object synchronously, which I can't, unless I introduce some mechanism (like async/await) to wait for that resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because your `console.log` statements are executing before your asynch `table.getTable('user')` has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Your `console.log()` statement are executed BEFORE the async function is ready. You need here also the `.then()` statements for the `Promise` function, so that your data is now in the table I show you in my code:

```
// db_user.js
var dbutils = require('./dbutils');

function getUserTable() {
  dbutils.getTable('user')
    .then(function(table) {
      console.log("table: " + JSON.stringify(table));
      console.log("dbuser.getUserTable is returning table: " + table.getName());
      return table;
    })
}
```

Please try my code and tell me about error

Comment: Just to clarify this fundamentally changes how `getUserTable()` itself should be called, so if the caller is expecting a synchronous result, it's impossible to give it one. I'll remove my downvote because your answer is no longer blatantly wrong, but you need to explain this difference.